# What are arm-none-eabi-c++ and arm-none-eabi-cpp for?

Tags: gcc, arm, embedded, newlib

I'm using the GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain to cross-compile on Windows, and was wondering what the following highlighted executables were used for.  There are already `arm-none-eabi-gcc` and `arm-none-eabi-g++` for compiling C and C++ code respectively, so I'm guessing `arm-none-eabi-c++` and `arm-none-eabi-cpp` handle some sort of C++ pre-processing or linking of C++ libraries?

[image]

Comment: `cpp` is the preprocessor.

Comment: @KamilCuk Okay, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c++` is the common "standard" name for a C++ compiler. It's the same as `g++`.

`cpp` runs the preprocessor only.

Comment: So you could call ```arm-none-eabi-c++``` in place of ```arm-none-eabi-g++``` with equivalent behavior?  I am noticing they have the same size.

Comment: Yes. Sometimes c++ is a link to g++ (or, well, to other compiler).